# Javascript loop for each list without needing new classes and new functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am week at Javascript, I got a code like below from https://codepen.io/jenningscreate/pen/rYNqVR:

```js
$(".step").click( function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").prevAll().addClass("active");
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step01").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "3%");
    $(".discovery").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step02").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "25%");
    $(".strategy").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step03").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "50%");
    $(".creative").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step04").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "75%");
    $(".production").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step05").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "100%");
    $(".analysis").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$("#color").click( function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("blue")
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* --- Start progress bar --- */

.process-wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    max-width:1080px;
}

#progress-bar-container {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:65px;
}

#progress-bar-container ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:15px;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-40px
}

#progress-bar-container li:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:solid 2px #aaa;
    transition:all ease 0.3s;
}

#progress-bar-container li.active:before, #progress-bar-container li:hover:before {
    border:solid 2px #444;
}

#progress-bar-container li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#aaa;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:700;
    transition:all ease 0.2s;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
}

#progress-bar-container li .step-inner {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
}

#progress-bar-container li.active, #progress-bar-container li:hover {
    color:#444;
}

#progress-bar-container li:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    background:#777;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid 7px #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-top:40px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 13px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition:all ease 0.2s;
}

#progress-bar-container li:hover:after {
    background:#555;
}

#progress-bar-container li.active:after {
    background:#207893;
}

#progress-bar-container #line {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    background: #eee;
    height:6px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:57px;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition:all ease 0.9s;
}

#progress-bar-container #line-progress {
    content:" ";
    width:3%;
    height:100%;
    background: #207893;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #207893 0%, #2ea3b7 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #207893 0%,#2ea3b7 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #207893 0%,#2ea3b7 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#207893', endColorstr='#2ea3b7',GradientType=1 );
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition:all ease 0.9s;
}

#progress-content-section {
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content {
    padding:30px 40px;
    text-align:center;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content h2 {
    font-size:17px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#333;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content p {
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.8em;
    color:#777;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content {
    display:none;
    animation: FadeInUp 700ms ease 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    transform:translateY(15px);
    opacity:0;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content.active {
    display:block;
}

@keyframes FadeInUp {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(15px);
        opacity:0;
    }
    
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0px);
        opacity:1;
    }
}

/* --- ORANGE --- */

body.blue #color .drop {
    background: #207893;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #207893 25%, #2ea3b7 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #207893 25%,#2ea3b7 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #207893 25%,#2ea3b7 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#207893', endColorstr='#2ea3b7',GradientType=1 );
}

body.blue h1 {
    background: rgb(206,119,68);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(206,119,68,1) 0%, rgba(230,125,36,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(206,119,68,1) 0%,rgba(230,125,36,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(206,119,68,1) 0%,rgba(230,125,36,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ce7744', endColorstr='#e67d24',GradientType=1 );
}

body.blue li.active:after {
    background:#e67d24;
}

body.blue #line-progress {
    background: rgb(206,119,68);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(206,119,68,1) 0%, rgba(230,125,36,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(206,119,68,1) 0%,rgba(230,125,36,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(206,119,68,1) 0%,rgba(230,125,36,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ce7744', endColorstr='#e67d24',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

<h1>Our Process</h1>

<div class="process-wrapper">
<div id="progress-bar-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="step step01 active"><div class="step-inner">Discovery</div></li>
        <li class="step step02"><div class="step-inner">Strategy Development</div></li>
        <li class="step step03"><div class="step-inner">Creative Concepting</div></li>
        <li class="step step04"><div class="step-inner">Production &amp; Execution</div></li>
        <li class="step step05"><div class="step-inner">Ongoing Analysis &amp; Results</div></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="line">
        <div id="line-progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="progress-content-section">
    <div class="section-content discovery active">
        <h2>Discovery</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content strategy">
        <h2>Strategy Development</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content creative">
        <h2>Creative Concepting</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content production">
        <h2>Production &amp; Execution</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content analysis">
        <h2>Ongoing Analysis &amp; Results</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Question is: Is it possible to loop each steps without creating new functions for new list that has same class? So I want add more list with same class, I don't want to add JS function for that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logic, step01 through step05 contains mostly the same logic, they just need to set the progress to different percentages and show a different pane. These information can be stored in the DOM as part of the `data-` attribute, e.g.:

```
<ul>
  <li class="step active" data-progress="3" data-target-class="discovery"><div class="step-inner">Discovery</div></li>
  <li class="step" data-progress="25" data-target-class="strategy"><div class="step-inner">Strategy Development</div></li>
  <li class="step" data-progress="50" data-target-class="creative"><div class="step-inner">Creative Concepting</div></li>
  <li class="step" data-progress="75" data-target-class="production"><div class="step-inner">Production &amp; Execution</div></li>
  <li class="step" data-progress="100" data-target-class="analysis"><div class="step-inner">Ongoing Analysis &amp; Results</div></li>
</ul>
```

Then, it is a matter of accessing the values of these datasets and them using them in your logic:

```
$(".step").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active").prevAll().addClass("active");
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass("active");

    $("#line-progress").css("width", `${this.dataset.progress}%`);
    $(`.${this.dataset.targetClass}`)
        .addClass("active")
        .siblings()
        .removeClass("active");
});
```